# MySQLdb: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to insert some data into a MySQL database, using Python and MySQLdb. When I execute the following function in my program, MySQL returns error "1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'"

User, password and database are correct, the table is existing and all rights are granted.

```
def write_to_mysql(pname, dat, like, reachs, talker, friendsfans):
''
    try:
        con = mdb.connect(user='user', passwd='password', host='localhost', db='database');
    except Exception. err:
        print(err)

    with con:

        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO fbinsights (page, datum, likes, reach, talking, fanfriends) VALUES( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (pname, dat, like, reachs, talker, friendsfans))

    connection.commit()
```

Where's the mistake?

Full traceback:

```
File "insights.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "insights.py", line 108, in main
    write_to_mysql(PAGE_NAME, date, likes_atm, reach_day, talking_day, friends_of_fans)
  File "insights.py", line 90, in write_to_mysql
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO fbinsights (page, datum, likes, reach, talking, fanfriends) VALUES( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (pname, dat, like, reachs, talker, friendsfans))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-freebsd-9.0-RELEASE-p3-amd64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-freebsd-9.0-RELEASE-p3-amd64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

Comment: On connect or execute? Show the full traceback!

Comment: There is a missing ")" at the end of "cur.execute("INSERT INTO fbinsights (page, datum, likes, reach, talking, fanfriends) VALUES( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (pname, dat, like, reachs, talker, friendsfans)" line. Is it same in your actual code?

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge Copy and Paste-error. Fixed it in the question

Comment: Is this really your actual code? There is still a syntax error (in exception clause).

Comment: Are you sure the code segment you have posted is same as the one you are using? Because in the stack trace, I can see the parameter of write_to_mysql as "friends_of_fans" but the passed variable in  the cur.execute method is "friendsfans".

Comment: However, I guess that some of your arguments has a wrong type. Can you confirm the value and type from each of `(pname, dat, like, reachs, talker, friendsfans)`.

Comment: @schlamar well, a '.' instead of a ','. Right. But this is not the problem. We don't hit the exception. Furthermore the sql-clause works via mysql-client.

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge I simplified the code for stackoverflow because of readability. It seems I put in some errors in this process. :/

Comment: @schlamar Table is: id(autoincrement, not null), pname Varchar(64), dat Date, like INT, reachs INT, talker INT, friendsfans INT

Comment: And type of the variables you actually insert? I think there is the problem.

Comment: @schlamar Well, the date has to be a string. There was the mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@schlamar answered it. Wrong types passed to MySQL.

Comment: Correct, that's the error message I get when passing the wrong types (e.g. python `datetime` object for a mysql `TIMESTAMP` field)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was generating a `SELECT` query with columns to select enclosed (by mistake) in parentheses: `SELECT (id, name, age) FROM members`;

Note that it does not raise this error if you have just one column listed in parentheses.